# R Error: expecting a single value what does it mean?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, summarization

I'm doing a simple operation using dplyr in R and got 'expecting single value' error

```
test <- data.frame(a=rep("item",3),b=c("step1","step2","step3"))
test%>%group_by(a)%>%(summarize(seq=paste0(b))
```

I've seen similar threads but those use cases were more complex, and I couldn't figure out why these 2 lines don't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you only have one group ("item") the `paste0` will get a vector of the three items in `b` as input and will return a vector of three strings, but your summarize is expecting a single value (since there is only one group). You need to `collapse` the `paste0` to a single string like this:

```
library(dplyr)
test <- data.frame(a=rep("item",3), b=c("step1","step2","step3"))
test %>% group_by(a) %>% summarize(seq = paste0(b, collapse = ""))
```